# how to implement nested array in typescript

Tags: typescript

i don't understand how i can define some variable in typescript:

```
interface ItemType {
    name: string;
    val: string;
    id: number;
}

const items: ItemType[] | ItemType[][] = [
    { name: 'russia', val: 'ru', id: 1 },
    { name: 'england', val: 'en', id: 2 },
    { name: 'america', val: 'us', id: 3 },
    { name: 'canada', val: 'ca', id: 4 },
    { name: 'ukraine', val: 'uc', id: 5 },
    [
        { name: 'havana', val: 'hv', id: 6 },
        { name: 'argentina', val: 'ar', id: 7 },
        { name: 'kazahstan', val: 'kz', id: 8 },
    ]
];
```

By design, items can be array of ItemType, but in some cases, here can be one more nested array of ItemType, and i can't understand, how i can declare variable like this ? 
[This code obviously wrong :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMMb4.png) 
I think i must use generic types

Thanks.

Comment: How deeply nested can it be?  Just two levels?

Comment: @jcalz yes. only two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These declarations should do:

```
const items: (ItemType | ItemType[])[] = [
  {name: 'russia', val: 'ru', id: 1},
  {name: 'england', val: 'en', id: 2},
  {name: 'america', val: 'us', id: 3},
  {name: 'canada', val: 'ca', id: 4},
  {name: 'ukraine', val: 'uc', id: 5},
  [
    {name: 'havana', val: 'hv', id: 6},
    {name: 'argentina', val: 'ar', id: 7},
    {name: 'kazahstan', val: 'kz', id: 8},
  ]
];
```

or:

```
const items: Array<ItemType | ItemType[]> = [
  {name: 'russia', val: 'ru', id: 1},
  {name: 'england', val: 'en', id: 2},
  {name: 'america', val: 'us', id: 3},
  {name: 'canada', val: 'ca', id: 4},
  {name: 'ukraine', val: 'uc', id: 5},
  [
    {name: 'havana', val: 'hv', id: 6},
    {name: 'argentina', val: 'ar', id: 7},
    {name: 'kazahstan', val: 'kz', id: 8},
  ]
];
```

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛитвиненко You're welcome. You should probably accept the answer while you're at it :)